# Devise omniauth-facebook redirect_uri Url must absolute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

My Rails app when I tried to integrate `gem "omniauth-facebook"` with devise, I receive the following error on facebook: `The redirect_uri URL must be absolute`.

Following were my config

devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "ID", "SECRET",callback_url: "/auth/facebook"
```

My user.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
        user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
      end
    end
end
```

My routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
```

And Controller OmniauthCallbacksController

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}
```

To `config.omniauth` in the initializer solved the issue for me.

I also configured the `path` to be absolute like so:

```
callback_url: ENV['SERVER_ROOT']+'/users/auth/facebook/callback'
```

Comment: I am using windows machine. The auth just return me along string `http://localhost:3000/?code=AQA5fDoNEqTvJpZ-p`

Comment: I don't know how to access CA certs on Windows tbh. Maybe the second part of my answer helps you.

Comment: Getting this error now `uninitialized constant Users`, Just fixed the :ca_file

Comment: plseae update your code in your question. Also it looks to me like the error might be unrelated to your previous issue.

Comment: @d3bug3r how did you solve the issue? I tried setting an absolute callback_url but I get the following problem. In my **Heroku log** i get the following **callback_url**  path="/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=somecode"
I opened a question on stackoverflow, could you please help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549803/devise-omniauth-facebook-redirect-uri-isnt-an-absolute-uri