# Devise omniauth-facebook redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

thanks a lot for the advise. 
I **migrated to Heroku** and I have the following problem with **facebook omniauth** authentication. When I authenticate with facebook the **callback URL** does not work and I get sent to the homepage `https://barteringapps.herokuapp.com/#_=_` with the following log error message :

```
"redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.","type":"OAuthException","code":191,"fbtrace_id":"BT1wrRRo64m"
method=GET path="/" host=barteringapps.herokuapp.com request_id=8913218f-703d-4da0-9388-f59d3a97bb69 fwd="81.171.81.200" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=13425
```

In **development** the functionality works when I set *callback-url* in **devise.rb** and in the **facebook** App settings to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/auth/facebook/callback`

So to give a **more detailed log** (I omitted not important infos):

1. I click on the link for the sign in

   ```
   method=GET path="/users/sign_in" host=barteringapps.herokuapp.com fwd="81.171.81.200" status=200
   ```
2. I click for the sign in with facebook

   ```
   method=GET path="/users/auth/facebook" host=barteringapps.herokuapp.com fwd="81.171.81.200" status=302 
   INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
   ```
3. Callback from facebook, I notice that the **path** does not include my **host**

   ```
   method=GET path="/users/auth/facebook/callback?code='sometoken'" host=barteringapps.herokuapp.com fwd="81.171.81.200"
   ```

I already searched Stackoverflow for a solution and I followed this instructions
[Devise omniauth-facebook redirect_uri Url must absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304444/devise-omniauth-facebook-redirect-uri-url-must-absolute)

1. I added *:client_options*
2. I configured the **absolute path** like so in *devise.rb*

   ```
   callback_url: ENV['SERVER_ROOT']+'/users/auth/facebook/callback'
   ```
3. In heroku settings I added the SERVER_ROOT env variable

I have also the following doubts, as I had many problems with env Varibles, I installed **foreman** gem for my development. Foreman works as my webserver and loads the ENV Variables from a env file. I have also a Procfile with the follwing code:

```
web: bundle exec rails s

.env 
Procfile
```

The problem is that production still runs with puma and without Procfile

```
=> Booting Puma 
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:21255 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options 
[4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution hear, in the **Brasilian Rails Google Groups** community. I read the translated post in English and found the following issue.

in my `config/enfironments/production.rb` file i had

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'barteringapps.herokuapp.com' }
```

I was able to solve this problem by adding the `https://` to the adress. This is the code:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://barteringapps.herokuapp.com' }
```

Now the facebook login **works**.
This is the discussion where I found the problem:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rails-br/PqMHviahB50/discussion

The author of the post is **Diogo Azevedo Gouveia**